# Doctrine 2 DQL Security

Tags: mysql, sql, security, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

A DQL query sample

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM ForumUser u WHERE u.username = :name');
$query->setParameter('name', 'Bob');
$users = $query->getResult(); // array of ForumUser objects
```

The above example is a parametized query where name is set to Bob. As I'm trying to review code security in our project, I wanted to ask members of the doctrine community whether createQuery prepares the sql statement.

For instance, would injecting ' OR 1=1-- to the 'name' parameter alter the query being created by the entitymanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the greatest benefits of Doctrine and using a DBAL is injection protection.  It will use prepared statements to not allow injection.  Trying to add that string to the parameter will not result in a changed query.

My friend wants me to correct myself by saying that the greatest benefit of Doctrine is not that it's a DBAL, but it's an ORM.  This is true.